# Is timeGetTime a good way to meassure time for a gameloop?

Tags: c++, winapi

I was trying to create a gameloop with fps dependent on the speed of its iterations. To achieve this I wanted to use a platform specific timer that (in case of windows) used the timeGetTime function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timegettime) to calculate how much time has passed since the last iteration. But I found that the time it costs to call this function is already quite a lot (for a computer). Now I'm wondering if this is the right approach.

I created a simple test that looks like this:

```
Timer timer();
    for (int i=0; i < 60; i++)
        cout << timer->get_elt() << endl;
    delete timer;
```

The timer class looks like this: (begin is a DWORD)

```
Timer::Timer()
{
    begin = timeGetTime();
}
int Timer::get_elt()
{
    return timeGetTime() - begin;
}
```

Not very interesting, but here is a example of the result:

```
0 0 1 3 4 14 15 15 15 16 16 17 17 17 17 18 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 25 38 39 39 55 56 56 66 68 68 69 71 71 72 73 73 73 73 73 74 74
```

I was expecting this to take about 10 milliseconds at most, but on average it took about 64.
What surprised me most about it was how erratic the results were. Sometimes it prints up to 7 times the same number, whereas at other times there are gaps of 12 milliseconds between iterations. I realize this is also because the timer is not accurate, but still. As far as I know your pc should execute this program as fast as it possibly can, is that even true?
If you want to run your game at say 60 fps, you'd have about 16 milliseconds for every loop, and if calling the timer alone takes about 2 milliseconds on average every time, and you still need to process input, update, and render, how is that even possible?
So what should I do here, is timeGetTime something you could use in a gameloop (it's been suggested a lot), or should I think of another function?

Comment: For time keeping I would default to [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). In this case, specifically [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock). Unrelated, but you may also enjoy reading [Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/).

Comment: Did you use `timeBeginPeriod(1)` as explain in the documentation you linked?

Comment: You have the right idea, looking at the actual elapsed time, so that while it is often off by a significant amount, you self-correct. The OS and CPU can schedule things erratically, and it doesn't matter.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I... did not. That actually seems to fix a lot of issues. So pretty sloppy on my part but thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the QueryPerformanceCounter instead

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: *Why* use a platform specific solution when we have [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`'s implementation is not a quality implementation currently: it always unnecessarily queries the frequency, and uses unnecessary division. It is much slower than it should be.

Comment: @geza That *may* be so. But have you ever experienced it not being *fast enough*?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: my clock implementation is 2.5x faster than chrono. And it does the same. So chrono is much slower than possible. A time query function should be as fast as possible. For example, when using a real-time function profiler, it matters a lot (how much overhead time query has).

Comment: @geza Sounds like you should contribute to the greater good and submit some patches and/or papers up-stream to your standard library implementor/c++ committee.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: unfortunately, I don't know any reliable, functioning way to submit patches to Microsoft (I was talking about MSVC's standard library). It's not that hard to speed up that routine, though: query frequency once, calculate its multiplicative inverse (with something like libdivide), and don't use unnecessary function wrappers. That's all. For me, these give 2.5x speedup on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Timers from Windows Multimedia API is a good choice for animation, games, etc.
The have greatest precision on Windows Platform.
Qt use and qualifies this timers also as precise ones.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TimerType-enum

> On Windows, Qt will use Windows's Multimedia timer facility (if
>   available) for Qt::PreciseTimer and normal Windows timers for
>   Qt::CoarseTimer and Qt::VeryCoarseTimer.

Comment: *Why* would you use a platform specific solution when we have [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)?

Comment: Why not? If the solution is defined to be platform specific, why should someone use something else? WinAPI are wrapped, functions get updated and optimized without need to rebuild programm and std are compiler specific. Why do you ask that in each answer?

Comment: "Why not?" - because it's going to be a pain as soon as you want to port to a different platform - even if just to build with a different compiler/standard library to find bugs. Cross-platform code is (almost) always preferable to platform specific code.

Comment: What do you want from me? If you so much in love with std::chrone and it is (almost) preferable for you -> use it! There is nothing told about cross-platforms. Why should someone choose be compiler and libs dependent if he doesn't need that!? Author just asked about Time management function from WinAPI... Let it be...

Comment: I'm relaxed :) just stop commenting me